# Solution using complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

A ray of light is travelling along $\mathbf{i}+\sqrt{3} \, \mathbf{j}$, it hits a plane mirror and is reflected along $\mathbf{i}-\sqrt{3} \, \mathbf{j}$.  What is the angle between normal and the incident wave? It looks like physics but only concept is angle of incidence = angle of reflection along the normal perpendicular to the mirror. I know the answer is $30^{\circ}$. But I am interested if there is a way using complex numbers. Like by calculating the argument by fixing mirror at the origin.  Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't that angle be just half of the angle between the incident and reflected ray. The latter can be computed using dot product of the two vectors.

Comment: I can't think of a way or a reason to use complex numbers for such a problem, the simpler vector analysis is much easier

Comment: i thought symmetry might help

Comment: What motivated your question originally? I am always interested in the ways that the complex plane is isomorphic and yet also different from the real plane

Comment: Ya like using Argand plane @ William krinsman